# Localised custom fields

Tags: custom-fields, localisation

Is is possible to create localised custom fields? For Swiss client I need to set up a custom field with the contact's profession. There are three official languages in Switzerland and we would like to show the professions in the preferred language of the administrator. Is this possible with CiviCRM 4.6 (LTS). Also for sign-up the exposed custom fields would need to be localised.